# Adjust p-value of the all output or just the variable of interest?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I am running linear mixed effect models using the lme4 package in R with the following output.

```
> anova(model)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
allocation              0.03352 0.03352     1 21.943  0.9014  0.352750    
period                  0.40751 0.40751     1 64.104 10.9575  0.001533 ** 
treatment               0.00965 0.00965     1 64.104  0.2594  0.612302    
measures                0.71010 0.71010     1 63.944 19.0937  4.663e-05 ***
allocation:measures     0.00676 0.00676     1 63.944  0.1817  0.671354    
period:measures         0.02049 0.02049     1 63.944  0.5510  0.460641    
treatment:measures      0.25081 0.25081     1 63.944  6.7439  0.011659 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My hypothesis is most relevant to the treatment:measures interaction variable, as if this is significant, then the intervention was more effective than the placebo.
I have around 1000 outcome variables of interest as I am looking at genes.

I am just wondering which p-value I need to adjust for multiple comparisons? For instance, is it appropriate to just take the p-value for treatment_type:measures for each test (1000 tests) and then adjust using p.adjust methods in R?
OR do I need to include all p-values from each model i.e. all values above for every test (1000) and then adjust? i.e. save 7 p-values from each model for every outcome tested(x 1000 test) ?

Apologise if this is a basic question, but I just wanted to be sure.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting for multiple tests is a contentious issue with many possibilities. One issue to keep in mind, however, is that you’re getting all of those p-values because of a decision the software-writers made to display all of them. If you had to do this by hand, you just would’ve calculated the p-value of interest. Consequently, you only need to consider that one p-value from the printout…

…unless you see that some other p-value in the printout is low and worth mentioning. At that point, there is an argument that you’ve just considered all of the tests carried out in the table and should adjust for all of them.

Comment: Thank you Dave for the prompt response, your explanation is very helpful. To ensure I understood you correctly, essentially adjust p-values from each test that you are considering/ interested in/mentioning. If you see other pvalues that are low, but don't use them for your analysis or consider them, then you can justify why you wouldn't include them in your adjustments?

Comment: @JessH My argument is that you took no action based on seeing those values and didn’t even want to or ask to see them, so those are not part of the analysis.